# Why is my Visual Studio taskbar Icon animated

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

The icon for Visual Studio on my Windows 7 taskbar is animated with a green bar moving left to right.  What does it mean, and how can I stop it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6rxa.jpg

I've not got any extensions installed, but I do have resharper (version 7 until I can afford to upgrade).  I can't find anything relevant through google, and I can't see an option in the options panels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation is used to represent progress. It's the same as for file copies (for example). I've seen ReSharper do this while running unit tests. Perhaps that, or maybe another extension?

Comment: I've got resharper installed, but it shouldn't be doing anything - it's even cycling when I've not got any solution open.

Comment: So, closing and reopening VS fixed it... Will see if I can figure out why it didn't stop by itself last time.

Comment: ...and I've also seen ReSharper getting stuck, and leaving the progress mode turned on.

Comment: in my case I (re) ran the unit tests and this stopped the taskbar animation (which is surprisingly distracting when it's stuck on)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I am still experiencing the issue where the animation persists even though the tests have long finished (with VS2015 and Resharper 2016.1.2).

One way to get around this problem is to disable taskbar animations altogether:

[image]